# How to get TF_Input from TF_Operation using C api of Tensorflow?

Tags: c, tensorflow

I'm using C-API of Tensorflow 1.13.1.

After getting TF_Operation by TF_GraphOperationByName, I cannot find a method to get TF_Input or TF_Output, of which I want to get data type.

Below are the associated methods (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/c/c_api.h)

`TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern int TF_OperationNumInputs(TF_Operation* oper);`

`TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern TF_DataType TF_OperationInputType(TF_Input oper_in);`

In my opinion, it lacks a method like "TF_Input TF_OperationInput(int32_t index);"

```
TF_Operation *input_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "Placeholder");
int input_num = TF_OperationNumInputs(input_op);
for (int i = 0; i < input_num; ++i) {
  // Expectation: auto oper_in = TF_OperationInput(i);
  auto data_type = TF_OperationInputType(oper_in);
}
```

Please help me to find a way to get TF_Datatype from each TF_Input and TF_Output.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `TF_OperationInput()` ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L608)).

This methods receives a `TF_Input` ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L356-L359)) as an argument, which you can build using `{ input_op, i }`.